# Is it possible to automatically categorise user agent by device type?

Tags: r, user-agent

I have extracted some user agent metrics from a dataset, but I want to know if there is a way to also categorise those metrics.

Specifically, I want to know how many users are using:

- Mobile
- Desktop
- Tablet

I can of course manually go through one of the metrics - such as `os.family` - and categorise them this way, but it isn't efficient and I want to automate this.

Further to that, there doesn't seem to be a way to determine whether or not a device is a tablet (as far as I'm aware there is no tablet-specific OS); if that isn't possible, then I am happy to include `tablet` under the `mobile` category as tablets are indeed mobile devices by definition.

At present I am using the `uaparserjs` package as it appears to do the job relatively well, with the exception being this lack of categorisation.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm also open to other suggestions or recommendations if they prove to be better solutions to the one I am currently using.

Here are the first 20 rows of the extracted user agent data:

```
ua <- structure(list(userAgent = c("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/23.1.148956103 Mobile/14D27 Safari/600.1.4", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.4.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14D27 Safari/602.1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 9000.82.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; Nexus 5X Build/N2G47Z) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14F89 Safari/602.1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14F89 Safari/602.1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; GT-I9195 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.89 Mobile Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-J320F Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.107 Mobile Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36"
), ua.family = c("Mobile Safari", "Chrome", "Mobile Safari", 
"IE", "Chrome", "Chrome", "IE", "Mobile Safari", "Chrome", "Chrome Mobile", 
"Mobile Safari", "Mobile Safari", "Mobile Safari", "Mobile Safari", 
"Chrome", "Chrome Mobile", "Mobile Safari", "Mobile Safari", 
"Chrome Mobile", "Chrome"), ua.major = c("10", "56", "10", "11", 
"58", "56", "11", "10", "59", "59", "10", "10", "10", "10", "60", 
"50", "10", "10", "60", "61"), ua.minor = c("2", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0"), ua.patch = c("1", "2924", NA, NA, "3029", "2924", 
NA, NA, "3071", "3071", NA, NA, NA, NA, "3112", "2661", NA, NA, 
"3112", "3163"), os.family = c("iOS", "Windows 8.1", "iOS", "Windows 8.1", 
"Windows 7", "Chrome OS", "Windows 7", "iOS", "Windows 10", "Android", 
"iOS", "iOS", "iOS", "iOS", "Windows 8", "Android", "iOS", "iOS", 
"Android", "Windows 10"), os.major = c("10", NA, "10", NA, NA, 
"9000", NA, "10", NA, "7", "10", "10", "10", "10", NA, "4", "10", 
"10", "5", NA), os.minor = c("2", NA, "2", NA, NA, "82", NA, 
"0", NA, "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", NA, "2", "3", "3", "1", NA), 
    os.patch = c("1", NA, "1", NA, NA, "0", NA, "1", NA, "2", 
    "2", "3", "2", "3", NA, "2", "3", "3", "1", NA), device.family = c("iPhone", 
    "Other", "iPhone", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "iPhone", 
    "Other", "Nexus 5X", "iPhone", "iPhone", "iPhone", "iPhone", 
    "Other", "Samsung GT-I9195", "iPhone", "iPhone", "Samsung SM-J320F", 
    "Other"), device.brand = c("Apple", NA, "Apple", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Apple", NA, "LG", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", 
    NA, "Samsung", "Apple", "Apple", "Samsung", NA), device.model = c("iPhone", 
    NA, "iPhone", NA, NA, NA, NA, "iPhone", NA, "Nexus 5X", "iPhone", 
    "iPhone", "iPhone", "iPhone", NA, "GT-I9195", "iPhone", "iPhone", 
    "SM-J320F", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You can use `ua.family` too as per my view. Combine information from `ua.family` and `os.family` may be you can have a better result.

Comment: I could, but `Chrome Mobile` could be used on both mobile and tablet devices.  Also, I want to know if there is a way to categorise this automatically without having to manually do it via conditional statements, and your method would require a conditional statement.

Comment: If `Chrome Mobile` is used then you can corresponding check for `os.family` and it will give you the clear result.

Comment: Can you print the `unique` values for `os.family` and `ua.family`?

Comment: If I subset on `Chrome`, then the `os.family` values are: `Android`, `Chrome OS`, `Linux`, `Mac OS` or `Windows`. If I subset on `Chrome Mobile` then it is only `Android`. How can I tell if these are mobile or tablet devices? Also, we are digressing - I want to know if I can categorise automatically by device type (`desktop`/`mobile`/`tablet`) based on one or more of the parameters in the dataset in order to save me having to do all of this manual categorisation.

Comment: Here is a complete list https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings where you can easily classify among tablet or mobile too. Please let me know in case you need further help! Do you want me to write sample code? The only way is to compare your user agent.

Comment: So in short, there is no way to achieve this automatically and the only solution is to manually categorise the data? If you would like to write some sample code then feel free to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180283/discussion-between-saurabh-chauhan-and-musthedataguy).

Comment: There is no need as I want to know if this can be done automatically and this dialog between us has effectively established that it probably can't. I'll wait and see if anybody else can shed some more light on this for now.